# "Add Docker support" menu choice is missing from Visual Studio Mac IDE

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-mvc, macos-sierra, visual-studio-mac

I'm using Visual Studio Mac to build a .NET Core MVC web application that I want to run in a Docker container.
The solution compile and run correctly, but when I try to add the Docker support,
from the solutions menu, the choice "Add Docker support" is missing!

The Visual studio is the Community Edition 7.1 (build 1297)
The docker for mac is the 17.06.1-ce-mac24
The .Net Core is 2.0

Anyone can help me?
Thanks

Ivan

Answer (score 1):

Docker support was removed in Visual Studio for Mac 7.1.0.1297.

Docker support was available in early Visual Studio Mac 7.1 preview versions but was not stable at the time VS Mac 7.1 was released so it was removed.

Visual Studio for Mac 7.2, currently available on the alpha channel, does include Docker support.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find the add docker support worth it to be honest, as long as you have Dockerfile in the root of the project.  And your compose files up a level with the solution.  You can achieve pretty much the same thing.

It'd just be a pain to debug/attach straight into it.  I've never found a reason to yet, but that's just me.